# How do you find a word in a Discord message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have looked up as much information as I could regarding this topic but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for. Right now I'm learning to code my own Discord bot. I've hit a point where I'm trying to detect a specific word in a message like a profanity filter.

The only way I have come to figure out is by using "message.content.includes()" but this finds the pattern within words like if I were trying to delete the word "rot" it would also delete "carrot"

I also know excluding the ".includes()" meant that even if the word was said later in the sentence, it wouldn't detect it since then it only looks for just the message itself.

My goal is to have a code that if I wanted it to delete "rot" it should only delete it if it's a separate word anywhere in the message.

Thank you.

EDIT: I pasted my current code:

```
const profanities = require('profanities/index.json');

for (let x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
    if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x].toUpperCase())) {
        message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
        client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
        message.delete();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  let unallowed = ["foo", "bar"] //Words you want blocked
  let allowed = ["bypass", "words"] //Words that might appear in blocked words like glass in ass.
  let foundInText = false;
  let msg = message.content.toLowerCase()

  for (var i in unallowed) {
    if(msg.includes(unallowed[i])) foundInText = true;
 }


  for (var i in allowed) {
      if (msg.includes(allowed[i])) foundInText = false;
  }

  if (foundInText) {
      message.delete();
      message.channel.send('**Hey!** That word is not allowed here!').then(message => {
          message.delete(7500);
      })
    }
  })
```

**Edit:**
I'm afraid it isn't possible to only delete a certain word from a message if that's what you mean. But if you are trying to delete a whole message that contains a word I can understand what you are doing. Try this:

```
let checkMessage = message.content.toLowerCase(); // Puts the whole message to lowercase. If your profanities file is all caps change it to .toUpperCase(); but if it is all lowercase keep it the same.
for (let i = 0; i < checkMessage.length; i++) {
    let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === `{name}`); // Name of the channel you want the logs to go to, this will help if you want to change the name and not grab the ID of the channel.
    const profanities = require('profanities/index.json'); // Make sure this is the correct file path of the profanities json.
    if(profanities.some(word => checkMessage.includes(word)) { // If the message includes any word from profanities.
        message.delete(); // Delete the message that was sent.
        message.channel.send(`Oooooooh you said a bad word!`).then(msg => {msg.delete(15000)}); // Send the channel a message saying that they said a bad word. Then delete the message after 15 seconds.
        client.channels.get(logchannel.id).send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n${message.content}`); //Send the log channel a message saying that there was a blocked word.
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me getting down votes on a question. I posted my current code above to better clarify. I'm hoping to use something around that.

Comment: @QuazArxx I edited my post, I hope that code at the bottom helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the sentence into an array and look for the specific word, and then join in back after removing the word.

```js
var sentence = "rabbit ate the carrot rot";

function deleteSpecific(word) {
  return sentence.split(" ").filter(each => each !== word).join(" ");
}

var res = deleteSpecific("rot");
console.log(res);
```

Edit: You can intersect your message and profanities instead of using for Loop like below:

```
const profanities = require('profanities/index.json');

if ((message.content.split(" ").filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(profanities))).length > 0) {
  message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
  client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
  message.delete();
  return;
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post with my current code. I'm hoping to use something around there so it's less complicated for me.

Comment: @QuazArxx, i believe your message to be a sentence right, and profanities to be the blocked keywords?

Answer (score 0):

```
"rabbit ate the carrot rot".replace(/(?<![a-zA-Z])rot(?![A-Za-z])/,'')
```

To provide an idea, use a Regular Expression, such as the rule here, `rot` before and after the existence of a non-letter to remove the `rot`